# Exactly how bad is using 'mod' to clamp reduce numbers to a given range?

Tags: randomness

Let's say I'm naive and want to generate a random integer in the range `[0, m)`, so I do the following:

```
k = cryptographically_secure_rng() % m
```

where `cryptographically_secure_rng` returns a random integer in the range `[0,n)`.
Obviously, assume `m <= n`.
Now in general `k` isn't distributed uniformly anymore.

It seems to me that for any reasonably nontrivial value of `m` and `n`, this can't possibly cut the attacker's time by more than half -- and in general, it would seem to cut it by a much smaller fraction.
Yet my impression from security/crypto is that such a naive RNG would be catastrophic for the security of the system.

So my question is:
*How bad* is this from the standpoint of an attacker trying to attack a system by exploiting this function?

Could such a bias be abused and amplified (e.g. exponentially) to attack a system?
If so, in what kind of a system might this occur, and how?
If not, then is the problem worth worrying about, and why?

Comment: @those who migrated this question: I wasn't just talking about crypto though... imagine an attacker trying to DDoS a service by making it execute worst-case behavior on a hashtable. Or whatever.

Comment: I don't think it is a serious problem.  The distribution of k will not be uniform (unless n%m=0), but it will be close to uniform.  As an attacker I will start from zero and work up, rather than m-1 and work down.

Comment: I would like to understand how the modulo operation influences the uniformity of k. Can someone link or summarize the information for me?

Comment: @E.Rose  take for instance $n = 10$ and $m=7$. So, the value 1 has double of the chance to appear, because 1 % 7 = 8 % 7 = 1 ...

Comment: I think [this question already has an answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22767/11718). Unless $m$ is a factor of $n$, your RNG is no longer cryptographically secure.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage : ​ The distinguishing advantage increases by less than m/(2$\hspace{-0.02 in}\cdot$n), so it'll also be secure when that is negligible. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: To add to what @RickyDemer said, aren't current cryptographic systems *far* more difficult to crack than by a factor of 2? What's the problem here?

Comment: "the problem here" is that you've assumed `m <= n` but nothing else about m and n. ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer: Can you elaborate? Give me an example? Pretend I'm dumb. That tells me nothing about your thought process.

Comment: If m=2 and n=3, then using the simple method on true randomness would have a 2/3 probability of outputting 0 and a 1/3 probability of outputting  1. ​ (That differs by 1/6 from the uniform distribution on {0,1}.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer: Yeah so that's already way less than the one-half I talked about (I think that's the max too? I didn't really think about it). My question stands exactly as-is: why is that a real problem for a system that is otherwise designed to be secure? Who cares if the attacker saves 1/6 of his time?

Comment: ... "than" _what_ one-half you talked about? ​ (I only see a mention of "a _factor_ of 2".) ​ For example, if you used that as the keystream for a [stream cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher), then an eavesdropper could easily distinguish between [encryptions of long mostly-0 plaintexts] and [encryptions of long mostly-1 plaintexts]. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer: Yeah that factor of 2 is precisely what I was referring to. Your point about the stream cipher could be a good answer if you'd like to write one.

Comment: Modulo would affect the output distribution if range is not a multiple of the generator's range. Hopefully, it exists many ways to avoid the issue, see [Efficiently Generating a Number in a Range](https://www.pcg-random.org/posts/bounded-rands.html) for some examples

Answer (score 5):

The answer is that it depends on how much larger $n$ is than $m$, and also depends on the application. If $n$ is much larger than $m$ (say 64-128 bits longer) then you are fine, as pointed out by @Ricky Demer. However, otherwise, you will have bits that have a bias.

If you are using this key in HMAC, then it doesn't matter. However, in general, it can matter and can matter a lot. Thus, I strongly recommend against doing this without making $n$ at least 64-128 bits longer than $m$. If you want to see a work where small biases are used to recover plaintext, then [Analysing and Exploiting the Mantin Biases in RC4](http://eprint.iacr.org/2016/063.pdf) is a good place to start.